# How do I stop warnings in phpDocumentor parser when I inherit from an external library class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, documentation, documentation-generation, phpdoc

I've been adding docblocks to my code, and have resolved most of the build errors and warnings that the phpDocumentor script has generated and placed into the errors.html file.

However, I have one last 'class' of warnings in my current documentation build - I get a warning for every class that I have documented in my application that inherits from an external library (in this case, Zend).

Is there a way to stop warnings such as `Warning - Class AMH_Controller_Action parent Zend_Controller_Action not found` from occuring? How do I inform phpDoc that the parent is from an external library and possibly give a reference link to the Zend documentation?

Comment: Have you tried with the -q or --quiet switch? *This option tells phpDocumentor to suppress output of parsing/conversion information to the console. Use this for cron jobs or other situations where human intervention will not be needed.*

Comment: sorry - I should have been clearer - I'm trying to clean out the errors report that is generated at the end of the build process, not the console feedback.

Answer (score 2):

phpDocumentor itself does not have a native option to handle this use case.  What I've done in the past has been to create a dummy file that contains empty class declarations for all the "not found" classes, tagged these classes like "@package DoNotDocument", and used the runtime --packageoutput argument [1] *without* listing "DoNotDocument" in the list of packages to include in the output documents.  Granted, this is a hack, but the effect is to:

a) avoid "not found" warnings (because class now "exists"),

while b) not creating any docs for the dummy classes.

```
/**
 * @package DoNotDocument
 */
class Zend_Controller_Action {}

phpdoc -d ./src -t ./docs -po MyPackage1,MyPackage2
```

Now, something to ponder regarding your docs, if your classes do indeed extend ZF classes.  By not having phpDocumentor parse those ZF sources, your API docs for your classes will not show what methods etc that are inherited from those ZF parents.  If this was my code base, I would allow phpDocumentor to parse the ZF files, but would avoid having the ZF classes documented by *not* listing their inherent @package value (e.g. "Zend_Controller") in the runtime --packageoutput argument.

[1] -- http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#using.command-line.packageoutput

Comment: Thanks for the advice for the ZF classes - I'll put that into play today

Comment: hmm... I've tried this - the final report still says 'parent Zend_* cannot be found'

Comment: Verified that this @ignore hack doesn't work like I remembered.  Try the --packageoutput option shown in my updated answer.