# Suppress Class DocBlock errors in PHPDoc

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

Is there any way to suppress particular types of errors in PHPDoc, or direct it not to check for some elements?

I don't need a DocBlock for both the file and the class.  My typical layout is as follows:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Registration service
 *
 * Coordinates the registration actions for users.  These are ...
 *
 * @version a.4.2
 * @author My Name <me at example.com>
 */

namespace MyProject\Service;

use Other\Namespace;

class Registration extends AbstractService
{
    // ...
```

In this case, PHPDoc complains that I have no class summary.  I can remedy the problem by copying the DocBlock and pasting it immediately above the class declaration, but I'm hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, and I didn't test this, you could do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\Service;

use Other\Namespace;

/**
 * Registration service
 *
 * Coordinates the registration actions for users.  These are ...
 *
 * @version a.4.2
 * @author My Name <me at example.com>
 */
class Registration extends AbstractService
{
    // ...
```

At least the docblock should now be recognised as a class doc instead of a file doc, which is more accurate in this particular example.

To try and answer your original question, actually suppressing the error, you could try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6348235/1146033) (*it describes using the command line `--packageoutput` argument*).

Comment: The first "DocBlock" belongs to the file. If there is only one, then it belongs to the file. See [What does a DocBlock look like?](https://docs.phpdoc.org/getting-started/your-first-set-of-documentation.html#what-does-a-docblock-look-like)